# Complete, I'm often used, in truth. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> Curtail me thrice, I am a youth;
>   Behead me once, a snake;
>   Complete, I'm often used, in truth.
>   When certain steps you'd take.

Who or what am I?

---

Source: Gurgaon Times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is

> ladder

"Curtail me thrice, I am a youth;"

> lad

"behead me once, a snake;"

> [adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus)

"complete, I’m often used, in truth, when certain steps you’d take."

> ladder

Source: Google